# change width when resize window in a table with the property table-layout: fixed

Tags: javascript, css, width, fixed

I have a table with the property table-layout: fixed; and I am trying to change its width when I resize the screen using javascript taking as a reference one parent element, if i resize on the fly the table keeps the previous width and i have to reload the page to adapt it again to the correct size

```js
function setWidth() {
  var parentWidth = $('#width-ref').width();
  $('#table').width(parentWidth);
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
   setWidth();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
   setWidth();
});
```

```css
#width-ref {
 table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="width-ref"></div>
<table>
 <thead>
   <th>first</th>
   <th>second</th>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>first</tr>
   <tr>second</tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove css property value 'fixed' applied to table-layout and make it auto.

table-layout: auto;

And the apply width to dynamically from javascript.

Comment: changing it to auto works but it brokes the visual design of the table, that is the main reason of using table-layout: fixed;